# Not able to catch Hibernate Exceptions in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am new to Spring framework. Developing a web application using Spring 4.3 and Hibernate 4.

I configured the required beans.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="${oracle.driver-calss}" />
    <property name="url" value="${oracle.Url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${oracle.userName}" />
    <property name="password" value="${oracle.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${oracle.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${oracle.hbm2ddl}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show-sql">${oracle.show-sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wmosIIBL.model"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

This is my service class

```
@Service
public class ItemIBLService {

    @Autowired
    ItemIBLDaoImpl itemIBLDaoImpl;

    @Transactional
    public ItemInvnByLcn getItemIBLByDspLocn(String dspLocn) {
        ItemInvnByLcn itemInvnByLcn = null;
        try {
            itemIBLDaoImpl.getIBLByDspLocn(dspLocn);
        } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
            System.out.println(dataAccessException.getMessage().toString());
        }
        return itemInvnByLcn;
    }

}
```

DAO Impl Code: I purposely making some mistakes to create an exception. So please ignore code mistakes and help me in find how to catch the thrown exception.

```
@Repository
public class ItemIBLDaoImpl {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public ItemInvnByLcn getIBLByDspLocn(String dspLocn) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        SQLQuery sqlQuery = currentSession.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM WHERE ITEMINVNBYLOCN WHERE LOCATION= :DSPLOCN");
        sqlQuery.setParameter("SDPLOCN", dspLocn);
        List iiblList = sqlQuery.list();
        System.out.println(iiblList.toString());
        return (ItemInvnByLcn) iiblList.get(0);
    }

}
```

Hibernate is throwing the below exception which i am not able to catch the exception in service class.

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [SDPLOCN]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:493)
    at com.wmosIIBL.dao.ItemIBLDaoImpl.getIBLByDspLocn(ItemIBLDaoImpl.java:22)
    at com.wmosIIBL.service.ItemIBLService.getItemIBLByDspLocn(ItemIBLService.java:22)
    at com.wmosIIBL.service.ItemIBLService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$51d359cb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.wmosIIBL.service.ItemIBLService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eecd7652.getItemIBLByDspLocn(<generated>)
    at com.wmosIIBL.controller.ItemIBLController.getItemInvnByLocn(ItemIBLController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think I am missing something in using. Please let me know why i am not able to catch the exception thrown by the hibernate in spring service class even though I am using @Service and @Transactional in service layer and @Repository in the Dao Layer.

Comment: The issue in in the repository class, as the stacktrace explains. Please provide the code of `ItemIBLDaoImpl.getIBLByDspLocn` and please signal which line is # 22.

Comment: hi Luiggi, Please check now, I added the code.

Comment: In your code, your HQL query is `SELECT * FROM WHERE ITEMINVNBYLOCN WHERE LOCATION= :DSPLOCN`, you define a variable called `DSPLOCN` but you're setting parameter with name `SDPLOCN`.

Comment: Dao layer is throwing QueryParameterException and service layer is catching DataAccessException just catch Exception in service class and check if it works

Comment: I clearly mentioned that I purposely made some mistakes to create an exception. So please ignore those mistakes.I need to understand how @Repository converts the hibernate exception into SpringException.

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate.QueryParameterException` is not a subclass of `DataAccessException` (the one you are trying to catch) as you can see in its [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/QueryParameterException.html).
You should add this exception to your catch block if you want to catch it. It's a `RuntimeException` so the compiler does not say anything if you omit it like you did.

Try this:

```
try {
    itemIBLDaoImpl.getIBLByDspLocn(dspLocn);
} catch (DataAccessException | QueryParameterException exception) {
    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Careful. Usually `QueryParameterException` means that you have an issue in your code, so instead of catching it, you should review the code and fix it accordingly.

Comment: If you know please let me know how Hibernate Exception is converted into Spring exceptions as spring document says that you can catch Hibernate Exceptions using Spring DataAcessException

Answer (score 0):

You're catching DataAccessException which is not correct if you want to catch QueryParameterException. You can either catch QueryParameterException directly or or QueryException or HibernateException.

I would recommend catching `HibernateException` for all query related exception.

You can follow the hierarchy of DataAccessException here 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html

and QueryParameterException
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/QueryParameterException.html

DataAccessException is something more of a recoverable which means from code perspective everything is good and when hits the database something bad happened.

but what you're trying to do is something did not reach the database, it failed on attempting to create a Query hence DataAccessException is not being handled.

Comment: Then, why spring mentioning that Spring can catch hibernate Exceptions using DataAccessException

Comment: Because `QueryParameterException` is not something you should catch. Instead, it means there's an error **in your code** and you should fix it.

Comment: @Abdul I updated my answer to answer your specific question